# Можно ли использовать EcmaScript модули без сборщиков?

Tags: javascript

Вот основный скрипт main.js который импортирует файл math.js

```
import math from './math';
console.log('Sum: ', math(2,3));
```

А здесь сам файл math.js

```
const sum = (a, b) => {
   return a+b;
}
export default sum;
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>EcmaScript Module</title>
</head>
<body>
   <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда запускаю получаю ошибку на браузере: Access to script at 'file:///C:/demosite/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Как сделать чтобы ecmascript модули заработали? Спасибо за ранее

Comment: зависит от браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно запустить проект через веб сервер. Потому что модульная система не работает/ не доверяет файловой протоколу(file://) Можете использовать библиотеку для VS Code Code Runner либо через npx serve команду.